# jQuery Select2 values appended by formatter be made searchable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using a formatter on [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/index.html) so i can have a nice alignment of two elements ( code / description ), but the plugin only seems to be searching upon the description and not looking at the code / description as the whole text.

Probably because its only searching against whats inside the original `<option/>` and not on what is being appended to that later on.

**HTML**

```
<select class="foo">
    <option value="codex">description 1</option>
    <option value="codey">description 2</option>
    <option value="cod">description 3</option>
    <option value="code">description 4</option>
</select>​
```

**JS**

```
function selectBoxOptionFormat(state) {
    var originalOption = state.element;

    return "<span class='selectBoxOptionCode'>" + state.id + "</span><span>" + state.text + "</span>";    
}

$(".foo").select2({
    width:"350px",
    formatResult: selectBoxOptionFormat
}); ​
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/B2XAG/13/)

Anyone knows of a way around this ?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't just code your html with what you want? `<option value="codex">codex description 1</option>`

Comment: i mentioned that <quote>so i can have a nice alignment of two elements ( code / description )</quote> you'll understand the alignment on the fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like its possible to create custom matches in Select2. I've missed the section on their documentation page that mentions the possibility of searching based on custom option attributes as well. Sorry bout that.

```
matcher: function(term, text, opt) {
                    return text.toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase())>=0
                        || opt.attr("value").toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase())>=0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add this code - or manually add the value to the text in the html

```
$('.foo option').text(function(i,v){
    return this.value + ' ' + v;
});
```

Then in your format function, remove the value

```
function selectBoxOptionFormat(state) {
    var originalOption = state.element;
    var txt = state.text.split(' ').slice(1).join(' ');
    return "<span class='selectBoxOptionCode'>" + state.id + "</span><span>" + txt  + "</span>";    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/2ZLWU/

**EDIT:**

You can use the matcher option and add the value to the text

```
$(".foo").select2({
    width:"350px",
    formatResult: selectBoxOptionFormat,
    matcher: function(term, text,v) { 
        var txt = $(v).val() + ' ' + text;       
        return txt.toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase())==0; }
}); ​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/HudyG/

Comment: this is a nice workaround thanks for sharing. Fortunately the plugin does support custom matches and i'd prefer doing it like that.

Answer (score 1):

Without editing the select2 plugin you could do something simple like...

Appending the value to the description in your markup (or using jQuery).

```
<option value="codex">description 1 [codex]</option>
```

Then have your "selectBoxOptionFormat" strip it out

```
state.text.replace(/\[[^\]]+\]/, "");
```